# nginx server block with Symfony2 on Linux

Tags: linux, symfony, nginx

I am attempting to create a server block in nginx that will allow me to access a Symfony installation on my computer from the url (symfony-project.dev). The installation sites in a folder called 'my_symfony' in '/var/www'.

I see that the Symfony pages are served from within the 'web' folder in the Symfony file structure, from a file called 'app.php'.

The problem I am having is when I try and access the url (symfony-project.dev) I have allocated to this server block, it attempts to download the files instead of serve them. I have added code in the server block to parse the files as php so not sure why this is happening?

Here is my 'symfony.conf' file in 'sites-available':

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name symfony-project.dev;

    access_log /var/www/my_symfony/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/my_symfony/error.log debug;
    rewrite_log on;

    root /var/www/my_symfony/web;
    index app.php index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) 
    {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_index app.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

I have also created a symbolic link to this file in the 'sites-enabled folder'.

Can anyone see why this is happening? I'm reasonably new to nginx so it's probably a glaring error!
Thanks